# How to retrieve src path from the below string?

Tags: c#, regex

```
string str = "class=\"customer-service-rightside-content-widget\"> <div class=\"content_asset\"> <p><img width=\"1300\" height=\"426\" alt=\"\" src=\"~/media/C14BCC5F47D54252B371B67E718DAC02.ashx\" ";
```

How to retrieve src path alone from the below string.
I have tried a couple of regex patters but i am not getting correct results.I am using C# regular expression.

Comment: Do not use regular expressions for parsing HTML

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: You might want to give more information about why not to use a regex for extracting information from HTML.

Comment: Here is the classic answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3010968

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex

```
<img([^>]*[^*]?)>
```

## [REGEX DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/i9MmUr65XX)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML (available from NuGet). But you should include opening and closing tags (assume you will have `<div>`) for this string, because currently you have some substring with tags being cut:

```
string str = "<div class=\"customer-service-rightside-content-widget\"> <div class=\"content_asset\"> <p><img width=\"1300\" height=\"426\" alt=\"\" src=\"~/media/C14BCC5F47D54252B371B67E718DAC02.ashx\"/></div>";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(str);
var img = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@src]");
var src = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Result:

```
~/media/C14BCC5F47D54252B371B67E718DAC02.ashx
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little messy, but its quick and simple and you wont have to install any packages like some of the other answers:

```
string str = "class=\"customer-service-rightside-content-widget\"> <div class=\"content_asset\"> <p><img width=\"1300\" height=\"426\" alt=\"\" src=\"~/media/C14BCC5F47D54252B371B67E718DAC02.ashx\" ";
            int srcIndex = str.IndexOf("~");
            str = str.Substring(srcIndex);
            var endIndex = str.IndexOf("\"");
            var thisIsYourSrc = str.Substring(0, endIndex); // this will be the value that's in your scr attribute
```

**RESULT:**

~/media/C14BCC5F47D54252B371B67E718DAC02.ashx